How can I change color of one district in a city with geopandas?
I am trying to extract one district (Hostafranca) in the map of Barcelona.
For example, I want to make the following map. (Hostafranca is with red color)[text]Hostafranca in Barcelona
I tried this code by using subplots function.
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 16))

Hostafrancs.plot(ax=ax, color='b', edgecolor='#6a6a6a', linewidth=2)
BCN.plot(ax=ax, color='w', edgecolor='#000000')

plt.show()

But the result is this. There is no Hostafranca marked. How can I solve it? Is geopandas only for coloring by the data of other columns?
result
--
Thank you. It has been solved now. I don't know why this very simple and required action does not have a single API in Geopandas and Matplotlib.
f, ax = plt.subplots(1)
BCN.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='w', edgecolor='#000000', linewidth=0.2)
Hostafrancs.plot(ax=ax, color='b')
plt.show()


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
